# Determinant calculation (Using Vandermonde?)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to solve this determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & \dots & n \\ 
1 & 2^3 & \dots & n^3 \\
1 & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
1 & 2^{n-1} & \dots & n^{2n-1}
\end{vmatrix}

I have tried to use the Vandermonde's determinant to solve it.
I also got this determinant equals:

\begin{vmatrix}
 2 & \dots & n \\ 
 2^3-2 & \dots & n^3-n \\
 \vdots &  & \vdots \\
 2^{n-1}-2^{n-3} & \dots & n^{2n-1}-n^{2n-3}
\end{vmatrix}

But I can get any further.

Comment: What's the pattern for the entries in the determinant, exactly? (I don't know what to make of the exponents $n-1$ and $2n-1$ in the last row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general term of the matrix is $c_{i,j}=j^{2i-1}$, which is almost that of a Vandermonde matrix (this would be $j^{i-1}$. Let us call $\Delta$ the wanted determinant. Let $C_j$ be the column of the matrix we are computing the determinant. Then 
$$\Delta=\det\left(C_1 ,\dots,C_n\right) =2\dots n\cdot \det\left(C_1,C_2/2,\dots,C_n/n\right) =:n!\Delta',$$
where $\Delta'$ is the determinant of the matrix of general term  $c'_{i,j}=\left(j^2\right)^{i-1}$, which is a Vandermonde matrix. Therefore, we get 
$$\Delta  =n!\prod_{1\leqslant j\lt j'\leqslant n}\left(j'^2-j^2\right).            $$